# ajax not success because of html comment tag in response data

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have `<!-- -->` these tag on every page of my application which is on codeigniter.

When I am removing form_validation from `auto-load.php` these tags remove 
issue is that in ajax response I am getting these tag for that reason ajax not sucess and return me the error

> "Unexpected Token < in JSON"

```
$("#addfundtype").click(function()
    {

        data = $("#addfundtypeform").serialize();
        var arr=[];
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/json',
            url: "<?php echo base_url()?>doAddFunds",
            data:  data,
            dataType: "json",


            success: function(msg)
            {
                alert("sdfsdaf");

                if(msg.status){


                    alert("User Edited Sucessfully");
                    location.reload();
                }
                else
                {

                    $.each(msg.errors, function(key, value){
                        $('#errordiv').html(value);
                        $("#errordiv").css('display','block');
                     //   $("<span class='errors'>"+value+"</span>").insertAfter("#"+key);
                    });
                }
            },
            error : function(request, status, error) {

                var val = request.responseText;
                alert("error"+error);
            }

        });
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: can you post your controller code? easy to understand your problem.Try once removing `contentType: 'application/json',`.

Comment: ` public function do_add_fund_type()
   {
      $this->set_validation();
       if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
       {

           $results['errors'] = $this->form_validation->error_array();
           $results['status'] = 0;


       }
       echo json_encode($results);

   }`

Comment: why these tags are comming by validation addition in codigniter

Comment: @ShahneelAhmed : Please edit your question, don't put your code in comments, and try to format it a little better. Contributors are agree to help you, but it is a good way to render a good formatting.